Dynamically get 'url' of React Native app
If we have a React Native app built with Expo, when starting the app via npx expo start, we get this in our terminal:

Where it says: "Metro waiting on exp://192.168.100.8:8081". This 'url' depends on the current network we are connected to, and can change.
Is there any way to dynamically get this 'url' with expo? For example, if I wanted to create a screen that displays this 'url', how would I go about getting this value?
(I'm saying 'url' in quotes because to my knowledge it is technically not a url}
This can be found in the source code of expo, line:
Log.log(printItem(chalk`Metro waiting on {underline ${nativeRuntimeUrl}}`));

I want what nativeRuntimeUrl returns inside of my RN app.

There's a few options regarding the 'url' in the expo-cli - type npx expo start --help to check them out
Info
    Start a local dev server for the app

  Usage
    $ npx expo start <dir>

  Options
    <dir>                           Directory of the Expo project. Default: Current working directory
    -a, --android                   Open on a connected Android device
    -i, --ios                       Open in an iOS simulator
    -w, --web                       Open in a web browser
    
    -d, --dev-client                Launch in a custom native app
    -g, --go                        Launch in Expo Go
    
    -c, --clear                     Clear the bundler cache
    --max-workers <number>          Maximum number of tasks to allow Metro to spawn
    --no-dev                        Bundle in production mode
    --minify                        Minify JavaScript
    
    -m, --host <string>             Dev server hosting type. Default: lan
                                    lan: Use the local network
                                    tunnel: Use any network by tunnel through ngrok
                                    localhost: Connect to the dev server over localhost
    --tunnel                        Same as --host tunnel
    --lan                           Same as --host lan
    --localhost                     Same as --host localhost
    
    --offline                       Skip network requests and use anonymous manifest signatures
    --https                         Start the dev server with https protocol
    --scheme <scheme>               Custom URI protocol to use when launching an app
    -p, --port <number>             Port to start the dev server on (does not apply to web or tunnel). Default: 8081

    --private-key-path <path>       Path to private key for code signing. Default: "private-key.pem" in the same directory as the certificate specified by the expo-updates configuration in app.json.
    -h, --help                      Usage info

https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/#tunneling
